# Online collaborative team, connecting to 1 or more servers

Tags: vpn, proxy, openvpn

I have a team of partners working from different locations in the world. We all are connecting to our own VPS, as well as to a bunch of customers websites via http and ftp to other shared or vps servers. In most of the above websites, there are ip filters restrictions.

I am looking for a way for my partners and me, to use a single IP to access these sites, so I can allow access to only that IP.

I am also looking for this to be secure, when transferring data, ftp, sending passwords, etc, and also, if possible to have a reporting/monitoring console to see which partner connected where and when.

What is the type of service I need to look for ?
How do I search for it ?